# CSS: float of div container causes bottom banner to shift up

Tags: html, css

I am designing a webpage where I want to float a div container to the right of the page but when I try to do so, it causes the bottom banner to shift towards the top of the page by the header.  I've tried using various methods such as **clear:both** but this hasn't been helping me.

```css
    .page_contain_wrapper {
      width: 1100px;
    }
    .about_contain {
      background: no-repeat #FFF 12px 3px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
      margin: 40px auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      width: 800px;
      min-height: 500px;
    }

    .about_contain h1 {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 22px;
      color: green;
    }

    #bottom_menu {
      background: #17A74A;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #bottom_icons p,
    a {
      float: right;
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      display: block;
      outline: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #bottom_icons b {
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    #bottom_icons img {
      border: 1px solid rgb(128, 128, 128);
      border-radius: 3px;
      float: right;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #bottom_icons_container {
      height: 60px;
      margin-right: 210px;
      background: #17A74A;
    }
```

```html
<div class="page_contain_wrapper">

  <div class="about_contain">

    <div class="maincontain">

      <h2> Spin </h2>

      <!--  <div class="background"> -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bottom_menu">
  <div id="bottom_icons_container">
    <div id="bottom_icons">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/JeffPaitchell">
        <img src="images/footer_buttons/twitter.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/jeff.paitchell">
        <img src="images/footer_buttons/facebook.png" />
      </a>
      <p>Follow us online:</p>
      <p>Contact us at: <b>jpaitchell@gmail.com</b> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know why I cannot simply float the `maincontain` div to the right without the bottom banner div `bottom_menu` shifting to the top of the webpage.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Floats remove the element from the flow of the document, so you'll need to adjust your margins/padding to make up for the difference.

Comment: Not seeing a problem in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ymjuczf/

Comment: I actually found a solution to my problem by doing the following: 1) Increasing the width of 'page_contain_wrapper' to 1600px (You could also increase it to 100% if you like), 2) Adding 'clear:both' to the 'bottom_menu' div.  My problem is now fixed!  Thanks for all the support!

Comment: Soo... a discussion of the appropriateness of using floats on non-technical merits isn't really on-topic here. Just so folks know...

Comment: Can't we all just get along? :)